# Python. Deleting individual elements of a 2D list

Tags: python, list

I'm attempting to build a brute force sudoko solver. I have put in part of the code I am having issues with. The column function takes in arguments I and j which correspond to coordinates on the sudoku grid which have a number. I have a 2D list called potentials, each containing the numbers 1-9 in a list. The idea of this function is that the number which is found in coordinates I,J should be deleted from all lists of potentials[I][k] where K is an integer.

The issue that im having is that in line "del potentials[i][k][index]" results in deletion of every single iteration of int(sudoku[I][j]) in potentials, regardless of the values of I and K.

Im not sure if anyone could help me, if I've just made a silly error or that I've misunderstood something about the concept of a 2D list. have been trying to rectify this four hours and don't know where to go.

```
import csv

suduku = []    

def column(i,j):
    for k in range (9): #maybe should be 8
        #for p in range (len(potentials[i][k])):
        #if potentials[i][k][p] == int(suduku[i][j]):
        if int(suduku[i][j]) in potentials[i][k]:
            index = potentials[i][k].index(int(suduku[i][j]))
            del potentials[i][k][index]
            if len(potentials[i][k]) == 1:
                suduku[i][k] = int(potentials[i][k][0])
                potentials[i][k][0] = 13
                potentials[i][k].append(13)
                toupdate.append([i,k]).
 with open('/Users/ianholdroyd/Documents/Code/misc/suduku.csv') as csvfile:
        suduku = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' '))

potentials = [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]*9]*9

toupdate = []

#while any('.' in sublist for sublist in suduku):
    for k in range (0,1,1):
        for i in range (9):
            if any('.' in sublist for sublist in suduku):
                for j in range (9):
                    if not suduku[i][j] == '.':
                        column(i,j)
```

For further clarity I have put my complete current code in below:

```
 import csv

suduku = []

def column(i,j):
    for k in range (9): #maybe should be 8
        #for p in range (len(potentials[i][k])):
        #if potentials[i][k][p] == int(suduku[i][j]):
        if int(suduku[i][j]) in potentials[i][k]:
            index = potentials[i][k].index(int(suduku[i][j]))
            del potentials[i][k][index]
            if len(potentials[i][k]) == 1:
                suduku[i][k] = int(potentials[i][k][0])
                potentials[i][k][0] = 13
                potentials[i][k].append(13)
                toupdate.append([i,k])

def row(i,j):
    for k in range (9): #maybe should be 8
        if int(suduku[i][j]) in potentials[k][j]:
            potentials[k][j].remove(int(suduku[i][j]))
            if len(potentials[k][j]) == 1:
                suduku[k][j] = int(potentials[k][j][0])
                potentials[k][j][0:1] = 13
                potentials[k][j].append(13)
                toupdate.append([k,j])

def whichsquare(num):
    if num >= 2:
        return 0
    elif num >= 5:
        return 3
    elif num >=8:
        return 6

def square(i,j):
    x = whichsquare(i)
    y = whichsquare(j)
    for p in range (x, x+3, 1):
        for q in range (y, y+3, 1):
            if int(suduku[i][j]) in potentials[p][q]:
                potentials[q][q].remove(int(suduku[i][j]))
            if len(potentials[p][q]) == 1:
                suduku[p][q] = int(potentials[p][q][0])
                potentials[p][q][0:1] =13
                potentials[p][q].append(13)
                toupdate.append([p,q])


with open('/Users/ianholdroyd/Documents/Code/misc/suduku.csv') as csvfile:
    suduku = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' '))

potentials = [[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]*9]*9

toupdate = []

#while any('.' in sublist for sublist in suduku):
for k in range (0,1,1):
    for i in range (9):
        if any('.' in sublist for sublist in suduku):
            for j in range (9):
                if not suduku[i][j] == '.':
                    column(i,j)
                    row(i,j)
                    #square(i,j)
                if any('.' in sublist for sublist in suduku):
                    if len (toupdate) >= 1:
                        column(toupdate[0][0],toupdate[0][1])
                        row(toupdate[0][0],toupdate[0][1])
                        #square(toupdate[0,0],toupdate[0,1])

print (potentials)
```

Comment: You might want to reduce your code to minimum: make a [mcve]. This will help illustrate the problem. While you do this, you might solve your problem. But even if not, it would make it much easier for people to solve your problem.

Comment: @anatolyg done my best to make it more clearer